# Cannot install rstatix package

Tags: r, package

I tried to install the "rstatix" package but kept receiving the error message as below. I tried to change it to `dependencies =TRUE` but still had the same error message.

> install.packages("rstatix", dependencies = FALSE)
>   installing the source package ‘rstatix’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rstatix_0.4.0.tar.gz'
>
> ## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 384450 bytes (375 KB)
>
> downloaded 375 KB
>
> Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
>     unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019c.1.0/zoneinfo/Australia/Sydney'
>   ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘rstatix’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rstatix’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘rstatix’ had non-zero exit status

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try `install.packages("car", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: @J_F Thanks! I upgraded R to.R version 3.6.3 and the problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and no solution. The following code works for me :

`install.packages("rstatix", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")`